# dll is missing when running executable (libcurl)

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

I believe I have followed every instructions given, so I just have to ask the same question again.

I am trying to use libcurl. 
I have changed the following settings in my project:
Configuation Properties|VC++ Directories|Library Directories - here I have put the folder where the .lib file is found. I did this for Debug, Release and All Configurations.
Configuation Properties|VC++ Directories|Include Directories - here I have put the folder where the .h files are found. I did this for Debug, Release and All Configurations.
Configuration Properties|Linker|Input|Additional Dependencies - I have added the .lib file. I did this for Release, Debug and All Configurations.
Configuration Properties|Linker|General|Additional Library Directories- I have added the folder where the .lib file is located. I did this for Release, Debug and All Configurations.

The program builds well without any errors.

When running the .exe file, I get the error message:
.dll is missing from your computer.

I have put the .lib file in the same folder as the .exe file, but that does not help. In fact I have put the .lib file in all folders for my project, but the computer can't find them anyway.

How can this be explained?

Is it possible to build the program without errors if the .lib file is simply wrong? I use a win32 .lib file and I create a Win32 project, but I'm running on a Win64 PC. Does that matter?

Desperate for help. Been searching like crazy for three days now.

Bests,

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the "libcurl.dll" in the same folder as your executable (DEBUG or RELEASE). In case of debugging, the dll is expected in your Project folder because Visual Studio is setting that directory. The ".lib" file is only necessary on compile time, which is already successful in your case.

The DLL comes with the cURL Projekt or is build when building the lib. Usually you will find the DLL near the directory of the lib. Search for a "bin" folder.

If you use the 32 bit version, make sure that you use the 32 Version of the DLL. The DLL has to match with the EXE, not with the OS.

Comment: where do download